# File does not exist error. But it does exist!

Tags: apache-2.2

I moved a Zen Cart installation from a different server to a new one on Rackspace running Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.

I had everything up and running until today. My most recent actions to this particular set of files involve changing the owner of the files to a newly created group. My user is still the owner.

I am now receiving a file does not exist error on some files and directories that I can confirm do in fact exist. I can't navigate to the directory or any file underneath it in the web browser.

When I navigate to them in FF i get:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL  was not found on this server.

My error logs dont show any difference in the file being requested.

Any ideas as to why this would happen? Could changing the group have affected this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The webserver probably isn't in the new group. Put it back.

Comment: would adding the server mean adding "apache" to the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your log files to see what the server is actually attempting to pull.  I'd be willing to bet that this is either an issue with file permissions, or something in the servers config, related to document roots or some such.  Realistically though we really need more information, and maybe a few examples, etc...

Comment: I have Zen Cart installations in 3 subdirectories under the web root. 1 works fine. 1 works but not the admin directory under that. 1 doesn't work at all. They all have the same owners and permissions. Nothing stands out to me in the log files but I'm still looking

Comment: And all of the files have the same owner:group, and permissions settings?

Also, on the site which doesn't work at all, try requesting a specific file - even if you have to create a basic html file - and check the access logs to see what it returns for that attempt.  Post that here, and I'll see if I can help further.

Comment: When I create a test.html file. I can pull that up no problem. So it seems its a php related issue somehow? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This happens in IIS if you have a trailing backslash in the target directory the website maps to.  Might be worth checking in your Apache as well.

Comment: Actually I have Zen Cart installations in 3 subdirectories under the web root. 1 works fine. 1 works but not the admin directory under that. 1 doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the case differences between the requested file and the file on disk?  Don't forget that under most file systems used by Linux, Hello.doc does not equal hello.doc.

Comment: yes there are no case differences. I worked perfectly fine before. I have made no changes to any files since the last time I accessed them. and I believe I am the only one.